# Handling NodeJS's child_process in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

So I'm working on an electron app that should launch an external application when a button is pressed. It works, but if I close that app and press the button again, it'll start several instances of the process. Here's the code:

```
ipcMain.on("run_crystal", () => {
  var cp = require("child_process");
  executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Server\\CrystalDMServer.exe";
  var Server_child = cp.spawn(executablePath);
  executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Game\\CrystalDM.exe";
  var parameters = ["test"];
  var options = {cwd:crystal+"\\CrystalDM\\Game"};
  console.log("a intrat in start game si urmeaza sa ruleze " + executablePath)
  var Game_child = cp.execFile(executablePath, parameters, options, (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
    console.log(stdout)
    Game_child.kill("SIGINT");
    Server_child.kill("SIGINT");
    delete Game_child;
    delete Server_child;
    delete cp;
  });
});
```

Comment: .. and what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: It was supposed to be for a platform like Steam, for example. You hit play and it starts the game. But in this scenario you might find yourself in a situation where you want to hit play a second, or maybe even a third time. Well, the way the code was then, it would start running multiple instances of the game.. Fixed it barely, though.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code might be called multiple time, and you forgot to remove the event listener after things done. I don't know extractly how to fix it, but try this:

```
ipcMain.once("run_crystal", () => {
   [your code here]
});
```

Or:

```
ipcMain.on("run_crystal", () => {
   [your code here]
   ipcMain.removeAllListeners("run_crystal");
});
```

Comment: Nice to hear. Honestly I had struggled with it once too.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I used this solution:

```
  ipcMain.on("run_crystal", () => {
      if(if_started == 0){
      if_started = 1;
      var cp = require("child_process");
      console.log("mesajul a ajuns");
      executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Server\\CrystalDMServer.exe";
      var Server_child = cp.spawn(executablePath);
      executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Game\\CrystalDM.exe";
      var parameters = ["test"];
      var options = {cwd:crystal+"\\CrystalDM\\Game"};
      var Game_child = cp.execFile(executablePath, parameters, options,
      (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
         Game_child.kill("SIGINT");
         Server_child.kill("SIGINT");
         delete Game_child;
         delete Server_child;
         delete cp;
         delete parameters;
         delete options;
         if_started = 0;
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start a process multiple times, you have to keep track of already started processes.

```
 let runningProcesses = {};

 ipcMain.on("run_crystal", (event, arg) => {
   var cp = require("child_process");
   executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Server\\CrystalDMServer.exe";

   if (runningProcesses[executablePath]){ // boolean value for a single process or int if you want to allow multiple instances runningProcesses[executablePath] < maxProcessCounts
     event.sender.send('process-running', { process: executablePath })
   } else {

     runningProcesses[executablePath] = true; // boolean value for a single process or int if you want to allow multiple instances

     var Server_child = cp.spawn(executablePath);

     Server_child.on('close', (code, signal) => {
       runningProcesses[executablePath] = false; // or delete runningProcesses[executablePath]; 
     });

     event.sender.send('process-started', { process: executablePath })

     executablePath = crystal + "\\CrystalDM\\Game\\CrystalDM.exe";
     var parameters = ["test"];
     var options = {cwd:crystal+"\\CrystalDM\\Game"};
     console.log("a intrat in start game si urmeaza sa ruleze " + executablePath)
     var Game_child = cp.execFile(executablePath, parameters, options,(error, stdout, stderr) =>{
        console.log(stdout)
        Game_child.kill("SIGINT");
        Server_child.kill("SIGINT");
        delete Game_child;
        delete Server_child;
        delete cp;
    });
  }
});
```